# using Notes app app simultaneously on Sierra and Catalina systems

Tags: upgrade, notes.app

My main system is on macOS Sierra. I'm testing macOS Catalina on an external startup disk to see how my old machine will handle the new OS (I know it's late, but...) On the Catalina test system I'm worried about logging into iCloud because of Notes - and this is my question: Will running Notes on Catalina upgrade Notes, making them unusable on my main Sierra system? Will there be an "Upgrade Notes" button like sometime in the past, or would everything be upgraded by default? For the time being I need Notes to remain functional on my Sierra system so this is a concern.

I tried researching whether the subsequent OS's (High Sierra, Mojave and Catalina) upgraded the format of Notes but little information is available and I cannot tell if the new and old versions are compatible.

I'm king of wondering the same about Photos...